# DataTable to List with complex object?

Tags: c#

I have this extension method which converts DataTable to List,

```
    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
    {
        var map = new List<Tuple<DataColumn, PropertyInfo>>();
        foreach (var pi in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (table.Columns.Contains(pi.Name))
            {
                map.Add(new Tuple<DataColumn, PropertyInfo>(table.Columns[pi.Name], pi));
            }
        }
        var list = new List<T>(table.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var item = new T();
            foreach (var pair in map)
            {
                object value = row[pair.Item1];
                if (value is DBNull)
                {
                    value = null;
                }
                var prop = pair.Item2;
                prop.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(value, prop.PropertyType), null);
            }
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

But most time I have complex object classes like,

```
public enum ServiceCenterType
{
    MOLOffice = 1,
    Tasheel = 2
}

public class ServiceCenter : BusinessObjectEntity
{
    public ServiceCenter()
    {
        Location = new Location();
        Contact = new Contact();
    }

    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public ServiceCenterType Type { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
public class Contact
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Twitter { get; set; }
    public string Facebook { get; set; }
    public Emirates Emirate { get; set; }
}
```

In my DataTable I have columns like Contact.Address, Location.Latitude, etc? How to modify the above extension method to support my scenario?

Comment: recursion can be your friend. is there a way to not get it in a datatable at first?

Comment: have you considered using automapper?

Comment: Will Automapper convert DataTable to List<T>? Also what do you mean by `is there a way to not get it in a datatable at first`

Comment: im sure it could. could you change the input to not be a `DataTable` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch fields from class too, then trace property of them again

```
FieldInfo[] fields =  typeof(T).GetFields(); // Obtain all fields
foreach (var field in fields) // Loop through fields
{
    foreach (var pi in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
    }
}
```